# Clickable website URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I know writing `print "website url"` does not provide a clickable url. So is it possible to get a clickable URL in python, which would take you directly to that website? And if so, how can it be done?

Comment: In general, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a function of the terminal that you're using.

In iterm2, you can click links by pressing cmd+alt+left click.

In gnome-terminal, you can click links by pressting ctrl+left click or right clicking and open link.